# jQuery droppable redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery `droppable` and I am trying to redirect to another page once the `draggable` element is dropped.

Here is my code:

```
 <script>    
      $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({

          drop: function( event, ui ) {

             window.location.href = 'Section8.php';
          }

        });    
      });    
   </script>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>    

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
</div>
```

For some reason this doesn't do anything, anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you tried this `window.location= 'Section8.php'` ?

Comment: I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ecropolis/4k3jbgy9/1/ and it worked just fine. I suggest logging events to console.log() so you can make sure the drop event is firing. Also just to make sure you are aware; draggable/droppable are part of jqueryUI. Make sure those components are in your build as well as any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.location= 'Section8.php'` instead of  `window.location.href= ...` The window.location.href property returns the URL of the current page.

Comment: `window.location= 'Section8.php'` doesn't work too, in fact no event if fired in this instance

Comment: I think it's `document.location.href` or `window.document.location.href`.

Comment: @user3574492 may you paste your page within your question? It seems like you have a problem with the droppable and not the redirect function. Just paste your code and I will check what's really being wrong